# I'm getting a Local variable referenced before assignment even after declaring the variable on top on Python

Tags: python

I'm learning how to code on Python and here's my first code that I learned from a book. I want to add a score every time the user clicks on an apple.

Here's my error:

```
line 19, in on_mouse_down
    score = score + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment
```

I already declared a variable on top and every time the user clicks on an apple, I'm incrementing the score by 1. After that, I want to print the score to the console. Here's my code:

```
from random import randint

apple = Actor("apple")
score = 0

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    apple.draw()

def place_apple():
    apple.x = randint(10, 800)
    apple.y = randint(10, 600)
    
    

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    if apple.collidepoint(pos):
        score = score + 1
        print(score)
        place_apple()
    else :
        print("You missed!")
        

place_apple()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `global` keyword for this something like this.

```
def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global score
    if apple.collidepoint(pos):
        score = score + 1
        print(score)
        place_apple()
    else :
        print("You missed!")
```

Comment: This one works. At first I thought I need to remove the score = 0 at the top where I defined it because we are already defining it inside the function but when I did that, I got another error called NameError: score is not defined. So I put it back and it works. It's different from other programming language that I have learned before where you declare a variable on top and then you can access it inside your functions. I also don't know why the book did not mention about global function and yet asked to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

it's better if you didn't use global variables ,
but if you must,you should declare it at the first of your function

```
def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global score
    if apple.collidepoint(pos):
        score = score + 1
        print(score)
        place_apple()
    else :
        print("You missed!")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 scopes(a region where the bindings between names and objects hold) in Python:

- function
- nonlocal
- global
- builtin

In your case, `score` is declared in global scope while you intend to use it in a function scope, which is not allowed by default.

As others' suggestions, you need to add a `global scope` inside any function where you want to use it.

For learning Python, [realpython](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/) is a good resource.